# How do I make grep output to a file?

Tags: command-line, grep

I'm trying to find some stuff in a large number of text files, and I want the output to be in a file so I can read it at leisure:

```
grep -i 'alter table' *.sql >> tables.txt
```

grep (this is the Windows version of the Gnu tool) complains at the >>. I've tried piping and all the rest, and there doesn't saeem to be an option to define  an output file either.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried just a single >

Comment: Yes, tried that too. Same result

Comment: I'm assuming that grep is not complaining about the `>>`, but that Windows is.  I have to guess because you have not told us what "complains" means.  Never say "I got an error", but rather "I got this error: ________".

Comment: grep -i 'alter table' *.sql > tables.txt
grep: table': No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like Grep is complaining, not Windows.

Comment: The error is: grep: table': No such file or directory

Comment: Yes, grep is complaining, but not about the `>>`. Apparently single quotes don't work in windows, try double quotes. Though I have no idea if windows uses the same redirect syntax. You should really either look up a windows command-line reference or use cygwin.

Comment: Thanks - I did try double quotes first, and that gave a similar error which is why I then tried single quotes. I'll have another go on Monday. > and>> are supported redirection operators on the Windows command line, have been since Bill met Steve.

Comment: @Kevin Single quotes don't work in CMD. They do work in PowerShell. The redirection syntax is the same.

Comment: Understood - I was following the grep help example, which shows single quotes (valid for unix, I guess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works here:

```
grep -i "other something" *.txt >> tables.txt
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? This looks pretty much the same as what the OP has already tried.

Comment: @ali_m The OP may have typo'd it, because it works to search all the `.txt` files for `"other something"` and create the tabels.txt file.

Comment: It does work. It appears that using single quotes (following the example given in the grep help) was to blame after all, though this does not account for why when I previously replaced them with double quotes I got the same error. Maybe I was having a bad day. Problem resolved now.

Answer (score 5):

Reviving this old question, but it's among the first Google results.

grep outputs differently, so I needed to add this option to ouptut the results to a file:

```
grep --line-buffered
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/496582/why-cant-i-redirect-grep-output-to-file)

Comment: This is what I needed on macOS